# Is it possible to determine the maximum point value that can be awarded for a single Scrabble word?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of variations for a single scrabble game is a very very large, but finite number. Additionally, the number of possible words is a much smaller finite value. Is it possible to determine the maximum (upper limit?) point value that can be awarded for a single Scrabble word?

/I'm not a mathematician, so I'm sorry in advance if this isn't the appropriate stackexchange site for this question (but if it's not, which is??)

Thanks.

Comment: That there is an upper limit is an immediate consequence of the fact that, as note, there are finitely many configurations and finitely many words. My guess, though, is that what you are really interested in is in knowing *what* that upper limit is! If you take the maximum value of a letter, the maximum number of letters in a word that will fit in the board, and the maximum multiplicativ factor (two times or three times, I dunno) that appears in the word and multiply that, that gives a uppr bound. Of course, that is somewhat non-optimal, but does not depend on any extra information.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, a definitive value. Is this possible? Thanks for the reply/ accepting my question and not down voting me into the depths of stackexchangeshame

Comment: are you interested in legitimate scrabble words or in any random string of letters?

Comment: @Amudhan legitimate scrabble words.

Comment: The only way to come up with a bound taking into account only legitimate words is to do a systematic search.

Comment: random string=maths, legitimate words=need a computer

Comment: Almost certainly the maximum value must occur when you play along one side and hit _both_ triple word and _both_ triple letter tiles (doubling up on the triple letter tiles).  This _is_ (theoretically) possible because technically you _only_ need to hit those four squares (and you have 7 letters to play).  It is possible that the other letters (you need at least an 8 letter word) are already filled in to the gaps and then you construct the word around those.

Comment: Have you tried typing $$\rm maximum\ Scrabble\ score$$ into Google to see what comes up?

Answer (score 4):

Having done some digging, it seems that (a) this is not a maths question, and (b) there is no proof that the proposed "best word" is, in fact, the best. Essentially, someone found a good word in the 1970s and noone has been able to better it.

It seems that the current "best word" is **benzoxycamphors**, which is the name of a chemical. For example, [this article](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3754&context=wordways) gives an example in which it scores 1593. However, [this article](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4775&context=wordways) claims that benzoxycamphors is not sanctioned by the National Scrabble Association, and they favour the word **oxyphenbutazone** (1587).

The most interesting article I came across in my procrastination was [this one](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2426&context=wordways), which tells the tragic tale of the word **benzhydroxyquin** (2278).

(If you are interested, you should look up the back-issues of [Word Ways Magazine](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/). Perhaps am e-mail to their editor would clear up the current state of affairs.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a definitive list of legal Scrabble words. The informal rule says that the word has to be in whatever dictionary you have lying around the house, but I expect that serious play involves a more formal rule, with an official dictionary. Once you have this list (in electronic form) it's a fairly simple programming task to place each of these words in one of a dozen or so "good" places on the board, and see what scores they generate. The good places are the ones that touch "triple word score" squares, presumably. There are perhaps a few hundred million possibilities, but this should be well within the capacity of any decent modern computer. Password hackers do this dictionary-cycling sort of thing all the time.

All of this is just for a single word, considered in isolation. If you also want to consider additional scoring derived from words already played, then it's much more difficult problem, as explained in Jared's comment below.

Comment: Actually it's extremely difficult considering you have to take into account how many of each letter are present and what are all of the possible legal moves prior.  The maximum score depends on the words already played as well as the played word.  By itself RAZZAMATAZZ appears to be the highest scoring word (at 225 assuming it's a triple word and the Z and M are on the triple letter tile) but this ignores points from words you played off of (including getting an extra triple points from the Z and M if you play off words there).  _I'm guessing this is NP-Complete, but I don't know for sure._

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just considering a single word in isolation. I modified my answer.

Comment: I should also note that according to Wikipedia, there is only a single Z tile, so RAZZAMATAZZ would not be a possible word.

Comment: @Jared They invented [superscrabble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Scrabble) for words such as this...